# Why isn't my furnace type sorter working?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

So I just recently built an XP furnace system that also sorts items put in. Each item then goes to their respective furnace, smoker, blast furnace. If I understand correctly, I need to fill 4 of the hopper slots with named items and the 5th slot with the item I want to pass through. I did this to the first hopper and had no problems, however the second hopper allowed the named items to pass through to the furnace... What am I doing wrong?

[image: Sorter]

Comment: Can't tell without screens of your build, but the most likely chance is you directed the filter hopper down into the locking hopper instead of to the side.

Comment: Potatoes were first, the named sticks I used worked fine and I already tested it, works great. The second hopper for the iron ore doesn't, the named sticks get sucked into the blast furnace

Comment: Ahh that was the problem, I forgot the torches on the other 2. Thank you for the help!!